# ES6 object with keys as parameter of arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This:

```
x = ({ title, description }) => { console.log(title, description) }
```

Works like this: (at least in terms of accessing the variables)

```
x = (title, description) => { console.log(title, description) }
```

It was quite surprising to me. First the first method describes the passed parameter as an object with certain keys title and description, but what is even more surprising, one can then access the values as normal variables.

Is it some syntactic sugar? Where is it mentioned in specification? This new JS is quite confusing.

Comment: It's called [destructuring assignment](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment).

Comment: 1st one pass object with de-structuring object literal Like below:x({title:'A',description:'B'})=>A B. 2nd one is normal parameter passing.

Comment: [Here is an example from MDN on how deconstructing can be used to benifit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameter's_default_value)

Comment: its a syntactic sugar in my opinion.  When we have variable with same name as object properties,we use this.Say let a='A',b='B', we can write x= {a:a,b:b} as an object or x ={a,b} which is equiv to x= {a:a,b:b}

Comment: but you realize that in the body you dont acces the first parameter as an object but you access solo variables. so it must be some special syntactic sugar rule. but with all these unexpected rules the new JS becomes quite not understable

Comment: i know but this is not even destructuring, it is declaring an object that has keys title and description.. so its even more another rule + some special rule of accessing the keys just like normal variables. but console says it is destructuring though (if you dont pass any param)

Comment: hm so yes it is really deconstructing and that's the explaining of it.. interpreter takes the definition of the arguments like {title, description} and does the assingment of passed argument like {title, description} = {title:"", description:""} that's why it works as title and description in the body. but pitty this wasn't mentioned anywhere but ok.

Answer (score 1):

That is ES6's [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

Comment: ok but here you dont use assignemnt. here you declare the arrow function so its not assingment in my opinion. so it must be some other special rule

Comment: Object destructuring syntax, yes, but not an assignment.